# UNIX SILENT VALUE in Progress4GL .p does not work with variables while trying to send a mail

Tags: unix, openedge, progress-4gl

I have a .p where I have decalred a variable as below:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE vEmailAdress       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO INITIAL "xyz.com".
```

After some code lines, lastly I intend to mail a .csv that I create via code somewhere in the server. So I used the following:

```
UNIX SILENT VALUE('echo "Please see attached report" | mail -s "Test email message" -a /path/to/report.csv -r "New UI Report <noreply@sample-mail.com>" xyz.com').
```

This **works alright**.

The **issue happens** when I am trying to use the variable I declared:

```
UNIX SILENT VALUE('echo "Please see attached report" | mail -s "Test email message" -a /tmp/newuireport.csv -r "New UI Report <noreply@rentokil-initial.com>"' + vEmailAdress).
```

I have also tried like this:

```
UNIX SILENT VALUE('echo "Please see attached report" | mail -s "Test email message" -a /tmp/newuireport.csv -r "New UI Report <noreply@rentokil-initial.com>" vEmailAdress').
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Send options without primary recipient specified.
```

Please can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is likely the lack of a space prior to your variable.  You probably also need to use "user@xyz.com" rather than just "xyz.com".  I would write your code like so:

```
define variable emailAdress as character no-undo initial "user@xyz.com".
define variable cmd as character no-undo.

cmd = echo "Please see attached report" | mail -s "Test email message" -a /tmp/newuireport.csv -r "New UI Report <noreply@rentokil-initial.com>" &1'.

os-command silent value( substitute( cmd, emailAdress )).
```

Notice that there is a space between the end of the subject text and the "&1", I think that is likely where your original code goes wrong.

The use of SUBSTITUTE and OS-COMMAND makes your code more flexible and portable -- it is no longer tied to the UNIX command and you can quite easily abstract the command text with additional variables if you do it that way.

You  may think that your code will never run anywhere else but it costs nothing to be platform neutral.  Using UNIX explicitly binds your code to UNIX and there is no good reason to do that.  The platform neutral  OS-* statements have been in the language for a very long time now.  Since at least v6 if I recall correctly.

Comment: I clicked on the tick mark and up arrow on left hand side of your comment

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your first approach should work. But it seems to me there are no spaces between the end of your -r and the e-mail address.

```
"New UI Report <noreply@rentokil-initial.com>"' + vEmailAdress).
```

That would result in 
New UI Reportxyz.com).

Instead, try

```
"New UI Report <noreply@rentokil-initial.com>" ' + vEmailAdress).
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SUBSTITUTE command..
Def var v as char no-undo.
v = SUBSTITUTE('echo "Please see attached report" | mail -s "Test email message" -a /tmp/newuireport.csv -r "New UI Report " &1' vEmailAdress).
UNIX SILENT VALUE(v).

This will help you.

Comment: You are missing a comma prior to "vEmailAddress".